# Recursive algorithm for generating derangements

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, recursion, derangements

In a class of mine, my professor said

> The list of derangements of $\{a,b\}$ is $\{a,b\}$ and the list of derangements of $\{a,b,c\}$ is $\{\{a,b,c\},\{a,c,b\}\}$. Once you have all the derangements of an $n - 2$ element set and of an $n - 1$ element set, you can generate all the derangements of an $n$ element set by choosing one element $X$, forming all Type I derangements of the form $\{\{X,Y\}, \text{rest of cycles}\}$ and all Type II derangements by inserting $X$ into all possible derangements of the other elements in all possible ways.

I don't understand how this produces the derangements, and I'm not sure what is meant by "rest of cycles" and "inserting $X$ into all possible derangements of the other elements in all possible ways”.

Can someone describe to me how this algorithm works, through explanation, pseudocode, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your quote is slightly wrong. The list of derangements of $(a,b)$ is $\{(b,a)\}$ and the list of derangements of $(a,b,c)$ is $\{(b,c,a), (c,a,b)\}$.

The recursive formula for derangements $d(n)$ is $d(n) = (n-1)(d(n-1) + d(n-2))$, with $d(0)=1$ and $d(1)=0$.

You can infer this recursion from moving the first element to some other location (that's the factor of $n{-}1$) and then either having that displaced value avoid the first spot (which looks like an $n{-}1$ derangement, $d(n-1)$ options) or go into the first spot (so the remaining elements must make an $n{-}2$ derangement, $d(n-2)$).

For $n=0..5$, this gives $d(n)=1,0,1,2,9,44$ - more terms at [OEIS A000166](https://oeis.org/A000166)

---

To illustrate how this works, let's look at a derangement of four elements $(a,b,c,d)$.

Move the first element to some other arbitrary position:

$(\cdot, \cdot, a,\cdot)$

Then if the displaced element $c$ avoids the first spot, we have the derangement of three elements, since $c$ is taking the role of $a$:

$\color{green}{(d, c, a, b)}$
$\color{green}{(b, d, a, c)}$

and if $c$ goes in the first spot, we just have the derangements of $(b,d)$

$\color{blue}{(c, d, a, b)}$

And similarly if $a$ goes into any other spot.
$\color{green}{(d, a, b, c)}$
$\color{green}{(c, a, d, b)}$
$\color{blue}{(b, a, d, c)}$
$\color{green}{(c, d, b, a)}$
$\color{green}{(b, c, d, a)}$
$\color{blue}{(d, c, b, a)}$

Comment: Note that in updating your quote I have used tuple notation $(,)$ when ordering is important and set notation $\{,\}$ for unordered collections.

Comment: Thanks! I especially appreciate the addendum; it helped me visualize how the whole thing works.